# Qt Jambi Application doesn't work after exporting it in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, qt, qt-jambi, jambi

I have just started my first `Qt Jambi` application using Eclipse Klebr and now I want to release my application to runnable `jar` file.

I Export the file like any Java application I want to release it but I get warning message.

> This operation repacks referenced libraries, please review the
>   licences associated with libraries you wish to reference to make sure
>   you are able to replace them suing this application.Note also that
>   this operation does not copy signature files from original libraries
>   to the general JAR file

when I open the generated jar file it doesn't open or make any action but when I open any other `jar` file from any other windows builder project for Java without use `Qt Jambi` library it works fine.

So I hope anyone help and give some simple steps to follow to release my `Qt Jambi` application without problems and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by Release a jar file as any Java application in eclipse and copy all dll files in the Qt Jambi folder qtjambi\lib to the executable jar directory and it works fine